# Dragging and dropping images from the forms webbrowser into the forms picturebox in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net

I need help on figuring out how to drag an image from the forms Webbrowser and then drop it and display it in the forms PictureBox. This is my first year of taking VBS in school and we're currently creating our own windows form applications, our teacher went through the basics with us as far as creating the first tutorial program goes (Picture Viewer) but I feel like she doesn't really know what shes doing since when we ask for help she just tells us to search it online. Please help.

Comment: You can't create Windows Form applications in VBScript. Are you talking about VBA? VB.net? VB6?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure I figured what Visual Studio used was VBScript, but it may be vb.net

Comment: I suggest you find out and fix the language tag on your question accordingly.